# How can I add this specific link hover effect to a WP site?

Tags: css, links

How can I use [this](http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/jDmKo) css effect on a WP site ?

I've tried all kinds of copy paste, but this doesn't get me anywhere.

I'm kind of new to Wordpress and css, so I pretty much have no clue what to do.

Thanks

Edit to make the questions Stackexchange compliant :

The problem was that I was copying and pasting the code give in codepen.io to my theme custom css.

But as Bryan pointed below, I was using the wrong kind css. I simply pasted the css he provided and it works just fine.

Thank you all.

Comment: Use [WP Add Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css) which add custom css to the whole website and to specific posts and pages. 

Once you activate this plugin, next step is add these css code by copying and paste into Add Custom CSS > main css.

Every thing is done now just use same HTML into you post OR page and you can see at front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you weren't using the compiled version. That's not normal css in the example you provided, it's [scss](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SCSS_FOR_SASS_USERS.html). SCSS is a type of file for [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), a program that assembles CSS. SASS adds lots of additional functionality to CSS ( variables, nesting, ect ) which makes writing CSS faster. If you're new to all this, you'll want to learn css basics before diving into something like sass/scss.

However, you can still use it quite easily you just have to compile it (there's a button in `codepen.io` that says ***"view compiled"***).

Add the css *(I've included compiled css below)* to the end of your themes [style.css](https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/style.css) file. You'll be able to find this file by visiting this link (changing example.com to the name of your site):

http://www.example.me/wp-admin/theme-editor.php

If for some reason that file is not being loaded in your theme you can enqueue it the same way you did the font above. There's a [generator you can use](https://generatewp.com/register_style/) to make adding stylesheets, scripts, etc. easier.

**Here is the compiled CSS:**

```
a.hovereffect {
    color: #e84b82;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
    -ms-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}

a.hovereffect:hover span {
    background: #e84b82;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(90deg);
}

a.hovereffect span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

a.hovereffect span:after {
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #e84b82;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 105%, 0px) rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 105%, 0px) rotateX(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 105%, 0px) rotateX(-90deg);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 105%, 0px) rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

One last thing to note, is that it's possible to add css without enqueueing it by adding it to [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head). To use this method you would add the following to your `functions.php`.

```
function mytheme_load_hover_css_effect() {
    ?>
    <style>
    /* custom css goes here */

    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head'. 'mytheme_load_hover_css_effect');
```

Hope this helps and have fun learning wp!

---

### Update: I was in a good mood and put together a plugin to do this

https://github.com/bryanwillis/hovereffect-shortcode

Just download that and upload it as a plugin.

**Useage:**

`[hovereffect url="http://google.com" text="google"]`

You can also just use `[hovereffect]` by itself which will link to the current page and use the page title.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it simply works, although I simply pasted the css in my custom css (I didn't want the font). One question though : what should I do if I don't want this hover effect on all the links, but only on specific, chosen links ? (if I may ask a question again)

Comment: @Garry see the updated edit I made to the css by adding .hoveffect class to the links. This will allow you to only highlight specific links like you want, but you'll have to add class="hoveffect" to the links you want highlighted using the editors html tab.

Comment: Also I changed the span:after content from data-title to title so you can add link titles using the link popup on the post editor toolbar. If you plan on using this a lot, look into how to add custom styles dropdown to tinymce so you can just add the classes automatically by pressing a button as opposed to entering .hovspan class everytime. Alternatively, a shortcode would work too.

Comment: @Garry I updated the answer and included a plugin for you to be able to do this with a shortcode. Hope it works for ya!

Comment: @Bryan WOW, you rock. Thank you Internet, thank you Wordpress, and thank you Bryan. I can't use the plugin right now, but I will and let you know. Thanks again, really appreciate it.